# Get fortnight date using current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to write code in javascript to get fortnight(2 weeks) Date from today's date. Any advice or help available?

Comment: Do you mean directly 2 weeks from now, or rather the end of the week  two weeks from now?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek So for example, if today were 23/9, the desired result would be 4/10, and any date up to 4/10 would return the same date, as it is the end of the specific fortnight of which all those dates fall into.

Comment: @GL_D how do you know if the start date is in the first week or second week of the fortnight? Because your comment implies that you are not automatically assuming the start date is in the first week

Comment: @DavePile That is exactly the problem I am having. Would it be possible to calculate whether a specific end of week is the true end of current fortnight (compare current Sunday to number of all Sundays in the year some how?) and then use that end of week as the end of current fortnight if condition is filled?

Answer (score 0):

First get the current Date, then add 14 Days to it (2 weeks), finally then get the last day of that week:

```js
// Get todays day
var now = new Date();
// Add 2 weeks
now.setTime( now.getTime() + 14 * 86400000 );
// Then go to the last day of that week
var fortnight = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - now.getDay()+6));
console.log(fortnight);
```

Comment: This is what my initial thinking was, however if the initial date was in the 2nd week of a fortnight, the result would be the end of the 2nd week of the next fortnight, and not correctly the end of the week which contains the initial date. Any insight on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Using following function you can get fortnight date for any date.

```
function getFortNightDate(sDate){
    var param = [];
    var objDate = new Date();
    param.todayDate = objDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (objDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (objDate.getDate())).slice(-2);
    param.timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date(param.todayDate).getTime() - new Date(sDate).getTime());
    param.diffDays = Math.ceil(param.timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    param.dayCount = (14 - (param.diffDays % 14)) - 1;
    objDate.setDate(objDate.getDate() + param.dayCount);
    objDate = objDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (objDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (objDate.getDate())).slice(-2);
    return objDate;
}
```